# Adding labels to two side by side tables

Tags: tables, labels

I've places two tables side by side, but I can't get the labels right.

```
\begin{table}[ht]
\begin{minipage}[b]{0.45\linewidth}\centering
\begin{tabular} {l | l | l}
        a & a & a
        \end{tabular}
        \label{tab:NotreDame}
        \caption{Training on Yosemite dataset and testing on Notre-Dame dataset}
        \end{minipage}
\hspace{0.5cm}
\begin{minipage}[b]{0.45\linewidth}
\centering
    \begin{tabular} {l | l | l}
        b & b & b
        \end{tabular}
        \label{tab:Liberty}
        \caption{Training on Yosemite dataset and testing on Liberty dataset}
\end{minipage}
\end{table}
```

When I compile my code, I get question marks instead of correct references.

Comment: Is it possible that you complete the code snippet to a *self-contained* and [minimal example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228)? Regardless of that you have to put `\label` *after* `\caption`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to put the `label` after the caption, it will do if the `label` is put inside the `caption`.

[image]

Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx} % for inclusion of graphics

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[ht]
\begin{minipage}[b]{0.45\linewidth}
\centering
\begin{tabular} {l | l | l}
        a & a & a
        \end{tabular}
        \caption{Training on Yosemite dataset and testing on Notre-Dame dataset}
       \label{tab:NotreDame}
        \end{minipage}
\hspace{0.5cm}
\begin{minipage}[b]{0.45\linewidth}
\centering
    \begin{tabular} {l | l | l}
        b & b & b
        \end{tabular}
        \caption{Training on Yosemite dataset and testing on Liberty dataset \label{tab:Liberty} }
\end{minipage}
\end{table}

This is Table \ref{tab:NotreDame} and Table \ref{tab:Liberty}

\end{document}
```